# Set image bitmap not working in android marshmallow

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, drawable, android-6.0-marshmallow

When I set a `Bitmap` in an `ImageView` using the set image `Bitmap` method it works fine in android `kitkat` but in `Marshmallow` it do not work, I tried it by making the copy of the image `Bitmap` but no success, 
please help me in the issue any help will be appreciated

```
 PictureCallback cameraPictureCallbackJpeg = new PictureCallback() 
  {  
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
      Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

   int   wid = cameraBitmap.getWidth();
     int  hgt = cameraBitmap.getHeight();

    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), wid+""+hgt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap
                                        (wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);

      canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);

     Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark3);
        drawable.setBounds(20, 30, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()+20, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()+30);
        drawable.draw(canvas);


        lastimage = newImage.copy(newImage.getConfig(), true);


        if (newImage != null && !newImage.isRecycled()) {
            newImage.recycle();
            newImage = null;
        }

        imageview_visinon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageview_visinon.setImageBitmap(newImage);





        linear_capture.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        linear_okcancelpic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
  };
```

Comment: Are you getting any error..?

Comment: NO i am not getting any error

Comment: Try to debug and check..if you are getting the bitmap..

Comment: yes i have already checked it, its working in genymotion Nougat and not working in marshmallow device though i am getting the bitmap

Comment: Have you handled permission's for marshmallow ?

Comment: used marshmallow permissions or not ?

Comment: Yes i have added the permission for marhsmallow

Comment: I wonder about which permission you are not speaking?

Comment: Have you checked if `newImage` is `null`? It is when you set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes bitmap is too large. Thats why imageview turns blank! I think that here you can find what you need: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        if (!hasPermission) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                    },
                    112);
        }
    }
```